# Calculate the total number of combinations over n elements, where the number of elements in each subset is in {0,..,n}?

Tags: combinations

If you had 4 elements, and you wanted to find all possible combinations of those 4, you take the factorial. But, what if you also wanted to consider combinations of 3, 2, 1 and 0 (where you're still using those 4 elements)? If you have n elements, and want to find all combinations of n, (n -1), (n -2) and so on, how would you go about it?

Also, sorry if I didn't word this question correctly.

Answer (score 5):

If order **doesn't matter**, you can use
${n \choose 0} + {n \choose 1} + {n \choose 2} + \dots + {n \choose n} = 2^n$

The intuition here is that we're simply summing up all the possible combinations of different length-ed sets. We start with the combinations of length zero (there's only one - the empty set), and then add the combinations of length one (there's $n$ of them), etc. until we get to adding the combinations of length $n$ (there's only one).

Johanna's answer gives a good intuition of the $2^n$ value. Another way to think about it, is whenever we add a new element to the set, it *must* cause the number of possible subsets of that set to double in size. Think about it: All the previous possible subsets are still possible, but now we can create a copy of each of them that contains the new element - in doing so we double the number of possible subsets.

---

If order **does matter** you can use: ${n \choose 0}0! + {n \choose 1}1! + {n \choose 2}2! + \dots + {n \choose n}n!$

All we do here is multiply each element in the last equation by the number of different arrangements that are possible for each length. If, for example, we're considering a set of 7 elements, there are $7!$ different ways of rearranging that set. Note that this assumes that your set elements are unique (i.e. it's a proper [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics))). If you have duplicate elements, don't use this formula (because, for example, it will count the ordered set `AAB` twice, given that we can switch the positions of the `A`s).

Perhaps an easier way to think about the *ordered* case it we're just summing permutations of each possible length: $^n P_0 + ^n P_1 + ^n P_2 + \dots + ^n P_n $

Comment: If I have elements [A, B, C] then I can make [A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC]. I'm counting seven unique combinations, not 2^3=8

Comment: @DanielFreeman This will include the empty set, so [, A, B, C, AB, AC, ABC]

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is every possible subset of the set of elements (in this case $4$ of them). To find that, you can either choose or not choose every element, so you have two choices for each element. Hence there are $2^n$ subsets of a set of size $n$.

EDIT: If order matters then we have more of them: $n + n(n-1) + n(n-2) + \dots + n!$ in particular. I'm not sure what the closed form of this (if any exists) is.

Comment: I didn't even think of a power set... I feel dumb haha            Can you go a bit into more detail and explain why the number is (2^n)?

Comment: @JulianJefko There is a cool identity relating power sets with combinations: ${n \choose 1} + {n \choose 2} + \dots + {n \choose n} = 2^n$.

Comment: But, if I had 3 elements, A B and C, the possible combinations are A,B,C, AB, AC, BC, BA, CA, CB, ABC, ACB, and so on. So, I have more than eight. Im sorry, I should've said order matters.

Comment: @JulianJefko I edited it to include the answer if order matters. I'm not sure if there is a nice closed form in that case though.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you!

Comment: @Johanna I think you've forgotten ${n \choose 0}$. So it should be ${n \choose 0} + {n \choose 1} + {n \choose 2} + \dots + {n \choose n} = 2^n$

Comment: @Johanna I might be being stupid here, but can't you just find the orderings of each of the $2^n$ subsets, giving you $2^nn!$ combinations with order mattering?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for $\binom{0}{n}\cdot n! + \binom{1}{n}\cdot(n-1)! + \binom{2}{n}\cdot(n-2)! + \cdots + \binom{n}{n}\cdot 0!$.

There is a lot of information about this function at https://oeis.org/A000522.

Comment: Thanks induktio for the edit - technically the dot for multiply goes on the base line, the central dot is for vector dot product.

Comment: [Central dot for multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Notation_and_terminology)  is standard where a period is used as a decimal point. On this site, you will see the period used as a decimal point, almost never the comma.